# Legend - Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Tags: r, plot, legend

Hi the legend of this plot throws the error: *Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ*

Basically the plot without legend works well:

```
plot(sdAbc, ylim = c(0,0.2), xlab = "Observations", ylab = "STD values",
       main = "P1 - ABC")
  abline(h = mean(sdA), col=shades[1])
  points(sdA,col=colors[1], pch = 19,)

  abline(h = mean(sdB), col=shades[2])
  points(sdB,col=colors[2], pch = 19)

  abline(h = mean(sdC), col=shades[3])
  points(sdC,col=colors[3], pch = 19)
```

but if I add the legend I get the error

```
plot(sdAbc, ylim = c(0,0.2), xlab = "Observations", ylab = "STD values",
       main = "P1 - ABC",
       legend("topleft",c(paste0("A, m: ",round(mean(sdA), digits = 3)),
                          paste0("B, m: ",round(mean(sdB), digits = 3)),
                          paste0("C, m: ",round(mean(sdC), digits = 3))),
              fill=colors))
  abline(h = mean(sdA), col=shades[1])
  points(sdA,col=colors[1], pch = 19,)

  abline(h = mean(sdB), col=shades[2])
  points(sdB,col=colors[2], pch = 19)

  abline(h = mean(sdC), col=shades[3])
  points(sdC,col=colors[3], pch = 19)
```

can't figure out why?

Comment: legend isn't an argument to plot. It need to be run after (not in) plot.

Comment: remove the legend argument inside plot, and do legend(....) after all your plotting commands